# How do i define AppEUI?

Tags: lora, orange-api

I'm trying to add an lora device on Live Objects.

There is 'AppEUI' field on device registration form.
I don't know how to define AppEUI.

The FAQ explains:

> The AppEUI and AppKey parameters are specific to the owner of the object and/or the application used with the object (see specification LoraWan).

And the LoRaWAN spec says:

> The AppEUI is a global application ID in IEEE EUI64 address space that uniquely identifies the entity able to process the JoinReq frame.

So, i wonder if i can define appEUI for myself. I create my own EUI-64 address and just fill 'AppEUI' field of the form. Is that it?

Thank you.

Comment: (I'm also worried about making EUI-64 address....)

Comment: Which device are you using?

Comment: I don't understand what you say. Do you want to know my device's id or devEUI?

Comment: The name of the device you are using and from which company. Different devices have different methods of adding appEUI.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand your comment again. Are you saying about the device itself? Is company what you say hardware manufacturer?

Answer (score 2):

yes you're right, you can define your own appEUI
best regards

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.